# RelativeLayout Inside ExpandableListView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, expandablelistview, android-relativelayout

Is it possible to have a RelativeLayout (having more views like button, textView etc) contained inside of an ExpandableListView ?

I tried something like this :

```
    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expandable1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relative1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/button1"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ExpandableListView>
```

Can someone help me out on how to achieve this?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Comment: ExpandListview need adapter.Why do you put a view in a list viewGroup without a adapter?

Comment: you can give the relative layout inside the `ExpandableListView`'s item layout, which is defined in your `ExpandableListView`'s adapter